# I want to let the user define the variables on a plot with a vector. The problem is that the plot doesn't show if I use the coordinates of the vector

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a user-defined vector `par={b,d}`. Also, I have a user-defined function `f(b,d)`. What I would like to do is to plot the expression `f(b,d)=0` and label the axes with the corresponding names of the parameters. Up until now, I have tried this:

```
ContourPlot[f[b,d] == 0, {par[[1]], 0, 4}, {par[[2]], 0, 6}, 
  FrameLabel -> {ToString[par[[1]]], ToString[par[[2]]]}]
```

but I am getting the following error:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Evaluate`.

```
par = {b, d};
f[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2 - 1;
ContourPlot[
 f[b, d] == 0, {par[[1]], 0, 4} // Evaluate, {par[[2]], 0, 6} // 
  Evaluate, FrameLabel -> {ToString[par[[1]]], ToString[par[[2]]]}]
```